# How to dynamically change links based on previous input

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

On one page, I get the username and I am passing that (via Cookies) to the second page.

The second page has a frameset

One frame is links to topframe.htm

The second frame should point to a website like

```
http://localhost/id=username
```

The username is different for each person is different. So how can I make the second frame load a dynamically generated URL?

Comment: No server trip between page 1 and 2?

Comment: There is no PHP server or apache server of any type. We can only use Cookies, JavaScript or VBScript to pass data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a link to open within the same `iframe`

```
<a target="_self" href="#" id="link" />
```

And after getting inputs, do this..

```
function setUserLink (usernameFromCookie){
.
.

    $('a#link').attr('href', 'http://localhost/id=' + usernameFromCookie);
.
.
}
```

Comment: what is $('a#link').attr - i've never seen anything like this before

Comment: @CocoaDev: Sorry I forgot to mention, that's jQuery.

Comment: Does jQuery require a server? I can't use a PHP/Apache server